# Множественное или единственное число глагола?

Tags: глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

В предложении
"О чем говорят женщина и мужчина..."
Множественная число "говорят"  - корректно?
Или нужно говорит? И, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**О чем говорят женщина и мужчина.**

Здесь только мн. число, так как они говорят между собой (говорят оба, выбор по смыслу).

А вообще согласование делается по правилу Розенталя [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

5. Сказуемое ставится в форме **множественного числа,** независимо от своего местоположения, если оно обозначает действие, совершаемое **несколькими субъектами.**

Comment: Если подтекст вопроса в том что если женщина говорит, мужчине надлежит молчать, тогда, конечно,Розенталь отдыхает.